# invalid factor level with for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, na

Please, I can't fix next problem:

```
 str(state_table)

chr [1:54] "AK" "AL" "AR" "AZ" "CA" "CO" "CT" "DC" "DE" "FL" ...

 z <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 for (i in state_table){z <- rbind(z, c(i))}
```

This code returns:

```
 invalid factor level, NA generated

 In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "AL") :
```

Comment: If the answer has handled the situation you should checkmark it so others will not waste time when looking for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
> rbind(z, "AL")
  X.AL.
1    AL
> str(z)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables
> str(rbind(z, "AL"))
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ X.AL.: Factor w/ 1 level "AL": 1
```

So afer the first item is added, the first columns is a factor with one level and you won't be able to rbind any more since the input will not be in the set of levels. It should work if you set stringsAsFactors to FALSE in `options` (or if you set up the datafreame with more care as ahaving a character column rather than using the defaults.

```
> options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> z <- data.frame()
> str(rbind(z, "AL"))
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ X.AL.: chr "AL"

> for (i in state.abb){z <- rbind(z, c(i))}
> str(z)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ X.AL.: chr  "AL" "AK" "AZ" "AR" ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I try to fix with added "stringsAsFactors=FALSE" in the end of my expression, but I don't know about "options" settings.

Comment: Some very knowledgeable people recommend running with that global option. It would tend to cause problems if code were written with that assumption in mind and then exported to a site where it was not the default.

Comment: I have almost exact problem with rbind of rows with values that are seemingly supposed to be string, but by default treated as factor. The solution of options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE) solved my problem. I think that it should be the answer to the problem. But I'm not sure what would be the other implication of options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE), what impact it would have to to statistics analysing involve those string values?

Comment: Most of the time the functions that expect factors will work with character variables in the same manner.